# how to insert Text in Multiple Lines using Checkbox in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

iam newbie in android i am inserting text dynamically in CheckBox so i dnt have idea about length of text and i also have to insert a button in horizontal of Checkbox please let me know how can i insert text in multiple lines.
this is the checkbox array.

```
    <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/risktablerowcheckbox_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:background="@drawable/location_header_deactivedd"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/risktablerow_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
         </LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/risktablerowbutton_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"   
        android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/riskinfo_btn" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/info"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/risktablerowspinner_layout"/>
 </RelativeLayout>


String[] checkBoxArray = {"","","Reason For Risk Assesment Not Completed","","","Is the client prepared to provide details of theft-attractive stock or property?","","","If Other Scpecify","",""};
 CheckBox   riskCheckBox ;
    riskCheckBox = (CheckBox)riskTableRow.findViewById(R.id.risktablerow_checkbox);
  riskCheckBox.setText(checkBoxArray[j]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the layout width of the parent linear layout and the checkbox to wrap_content. Thus the text in the checkbox has no width constraints.

If you set the linearlayout to match parent, it will be as wide as the screen, you can then set the checkbox to have a width of match_parent and a height of wrap_content and the text should automatically go to the next line.

You may also want to include some right margin on the checkbox to ensure there is some space on the right before the text is bumped to the next line.

Comment: have you tried set a dp value to layout_width just to check if the text will actually go to the next line with the check box has a width constraint? try 200dp and see what happens?